# Split Pandas DataFrame on Blank rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isnull

I have a large dataframe that I need to split on empty rows.

here's a simplified example of the DataFrame:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   0   International
1   1   1   International
2   NaN 2   International
3   1   3   International
4   1   4   International
5   8   0   North American
6   8   1   North American
7   8   2   North American
8   8   3   North American
9   NaN NaN NaN
10  1   0   Internal
11  1   1   Internal
12  6   0   East
13  6   1   East
14  6   2   East
...
```

As you can see, row 9 is blank. What I need to do is take rows 0 through 8 and put them in a different dataframe, as well as rows 10 to the next blank so that I have several dataframes in the end. Notice, when looking for blank rows I need the whole row to be blank.

Here is the code I'm using to find blanks:

```
def find_breaks(df):
    df_breaks = df[(df.loc[:,['A','B','C']].isnull()).any(axis=1)]
    print(df_breaks.index)
```

This code works when I test it on the simplified DF but, of course, my real DataFrame has many more columns than `['A','B','C']`

How can I find the next blank row (or as I am doing above, all the blank rows at once) without having to specify my column names?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC, use [`pd.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) + [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
df_list = np.split(df, df[df.isnull().all(1)].index) 

for df in df_list:
    print(df, '\n') 

     A    B               C
0  1.0  0.0   International
1  1.0  1.0   International
2  NaN  2.0   International
3  1.0  3.0   International
4  1.0  4.0   International
5  8.0  0.0  North American
6  8.0  1.0  North American
7  8.0  2.0  North American
8  8.0  3.0  North American 

      A    B         C
9   NaN  NaN       NaN
10  1.0  0.0  Internal
11  1.0  1.0  Internal
12  6.0  0.0      East
13  6.0  1.0      East
14  6.0  2.0      East
```

First, obtain the indices where the entire row is null, and then use that to split your dataframe into chunks. `np.split` handles dataframes quite well.

Comment: @LegitStack Plus, your code had _any_... while you needed _all_ (which ensures that they're all True, not just one or two).

Comment: @cs95 how can we avoid the line with all NaN in the second dataframe: `9   NaN  NaN       NaN`?

Comment: @Heinz avoiding the line might be tough but you can remove it using df_master = df_master.dropna(how='all').

Comment: whats np in this solution?

Comment: @TomasLucena numpy `import numpy as np`